# How to set style only for mobile in zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I have a div element that is left aligned in large screens.
I want to center that element when it is on the mobile screen.
I am using foundation 5 framework.

```
@media only screen {
.simpleDivClass {text-align:center;}
}
```

I have added this in main css file but now 'simpleDivClass' is centered in all screen sizes.
What should I do to set style only for mobile screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { 
   .simpleDivClass {text-align:center;}
}
```

Because : max-width 40em is for mobile-only styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using foundation's Sass files, you can also use things like this so that your media queries are consistent throughout your project.

```
@media #{$large-up} { 
  .example {
    color: red;
  }
}
```